# How to commit path variable from batch to ps1

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a bat.file where I call my ps1-script.
I will commit a path to the ps1-script

**bat:**

```
...
set path="\\wka-wn-stda3\xKarten\A\"
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%~dpn0.ps1'"
```

**ps1:**

```
    $path="\\wka-wn-stda3\xKarten\A\"
...
```

I will take the path from the batch file inside the ps1-file. How can I realize this?
Hope someone can help me please!?

Answer (score 0):

1. Read and follow [about_Environment_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-5.1)

> You can also display and change the values of environment variables
>   without using a cmdlet by using the expression parser in Windows
>   PowerShell. To display the value of an environment variable, use the
>   following syntax:
>
> ```
>  $Env:<variable-name>
> ```

2. Do not set the `%PATH%` environment variable arbitrarily,  read [`%PATH%` command](https://ss64.com/nt/path.html):

> The `%PATH%` environment variable contains a list of folders. When a
>   command is issued at the CMD prompt, the operating system will first
>   look for an executable file in the current folder, if not found it
>   will scan `%PATH%` to find it.

3. Apply `set "varname=value"` syntax rather than <strike>`set varname="value"`</strike> (note position of `"` double quotes). Example:

```
==> set var="%cd%"

==> powershell -noprofile -command (Get-Childitem $env:var -filter "*.ps1").Name
Get-Childitem : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '"d' does not exist.
At line:1 char:2
+ (Get-Childitem $env:var -filter *.ps1).Name
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ("d:String) [Get-ChildItem], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand


==> set "var=%cd%"

==> powershell -noprofile -command (Get-Childitem "$env:var" -filter "*.ps1").Name
cliparser.ps1

==>
```